# Organizing PowerShell Cmdlet classes

Tags: powershell

...anyone an idea? is ther a Standard?

The PowerShell "cmdlet structure" is "verb-noun" - that is nice, but leads to classes organized by Verb. Now, the PowerShell "external Interface" is detmined by the CmdLet Attribute and has not have to havea relationship with the actual class Name.

My idea is to turn this around - use NounVerb for the class so everything for a specific noun is together, then pack them possibly into namespaces according to the "prefix" in the noun (i.e. if multiple cmdlets form Groups, those go into namepaces).

This shall Keep the lsit smaller during development and makes sure all cmdlets for an oun are grouped together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common practice I've seen (via dotPeek on S.M.A) is to name a C# cmdlet class for Verb-Noun: VerbNounCommand e.g. GetJobCommand.  This is what we do for the cmdlet class names in the PowerShell Community Extensions.

OTOH, I think this is an implementation detail that is completely up to the cmdlet author.  The most important thing here is to try to use an approved verb and pick a good noun (not too generic and avoid plural).

Comment: Agree on implementation detail - problem is, I AM implementing ;) So obviously this "detail" hits me.

Comment: @TomTom I wouldn't say there is a standard - perhaps a common convention.  I do find code like `GetJobCommand` more natural to read than `JobGetCommand`.

Comment: Yes, but at the same time it means you organize them by verb, not by - well - "natural grouping" ;(